# How can I prevent QuickCheck from catching all exceptions?

Tags: testing, haskell, quickcheck

The QuickCheck library seems to catch all exceptions that are thrown when testing a property.  In particular, this behavior prevents me from putting a time limit on the entire QuickCheck computation.  For example:

```
module QuickCheckTimeout where

import System.Timeout (timeout)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Test.QuickCheck (quickCheck, within, Property)
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic (monadicIO, run, assert)

-- use threadDelay to simulate a slow computation
prop_slow_plus_zero_right_identity :: Int -> Property
prop_slow_plus_zero_right_identity i = monadicIO $ do
  run (threadDelay (100000 * i))
  assert (i + 0 == i)

runTests :: IO ()
runTests = do
  result <- timeout 3000000 (quickCheck prop_slow_plus_zero_right_identity)
  case result of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "timed out!"
    Just _  -> putStrLn "completed!"
```

Because QuickCheck catches all the exceptions, `timeout` breaks:  it doesn't actually abort the computation!  Instead, QuickCheck treats the property as having failed, and tries to shrink the input that caused the failure.  This shrinking process is then not run with a time bound, causing the total time used by the computation to exceed the prescribed time limit.

One might think I could use QuickCheck's `within` combinator to bound the computation time.  (`within` treats a property as having failed if it doesn't finish within the given time limit.)  However, `within` doesn't quite do what I want, since QuickCheck still tries to shrink the input that caused the failure, a process that can take far too long.  (What could alternatively work for me is a version of `within` that prevents QuickCheck from trying to shrink the inputs to a property that failed because it didn't finish within the given time limit.)

How can I prevent QuickCheck from catching all exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

Since QuickCheck does the right thing when the user manually interrupts the test by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you might be able to work around this issue by writing something similar to `timeout`, but that throws an asynchroneous [`UserInterrupt`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#v%3aUserInterrupt) exception instead of a custom exception type.

This is pretty much a straight copy-and-paste job from the source of `System.Timeout`:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception

timeout' n f = do
    pid <- myThreadId
    bracket (forkIO (threadDelay n >> throwTo pid UserInterrupt))
            (killThread)
            (const f)
```

With this approach, you'll have to use `quickCheckResult` and check the failure reason to detect whether the test timed out or not. It seems to work decent enough:

```
> runTests 
*** Failed! Exception: 'user interrupt' (after 13 tests):  
16
```

Comment: Upvoted because this solution addresses the particular use case (i.e. putting a time limit on the entire QuickCheck computation).  Poring over the source code, it looks like QuickCheck is hard-wired to treat the UserInterrupt exception specially.

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't quite answer my question:  QuickCheck still swallows all but UserInterrupt!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `chasingbottoms` package would be useful?  http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ChasingBottoms/1.3.0.3/doc/html/Test-ChasingBottoms-TimeOut.html

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the main question, but your suggested alternative:

> What could alternatively work for me is a version of within that prevents QuickCheck from trying to shrink the inputs to a property that failed because it didn't finish within the given time limit

There is `noShrinking` which should work for that:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:noShrinking

As a downside, this will disable shrinking also if the tests fails for other reasons besides the timeout.